# perl object and attribute

Tags: perl, object

I am trying to create perl object (and its associated attributes), based on some conditions (for example the version of the object), a certain attribute is not needed (or invalid otherwise). How do I create the object, without having to specify the object twice (once for each condition).

```
my $obj = myobject->new (
attr1 => value1,
attr2 => value2,
attr3 => valuen,
)
```

Can I for example, define a variable and assign it different value based on the condition? Like this:

```
my $attribute = (condition)? "":'attr4 => value4';
```

and simply define the object like this:

```
    my $obj = myobject->new (
    attr1 => value1,
    attr2 => value2,
    attr3 => valuen,
    $attribute,
    )
```

This obviously will err out. But you get my idea. How do I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments to `new` are just a list — just like the arguments to *anything*, in fact. You can do what you want with an array instead of a string.

```
my @attribute = $condition ? () : (attr4 => value4);

my $obj = MyObject->new(
    attr1 => value1,
    attr2 => value2,
    attr3 => value3,
    @attribute
);
```

You can also use a hash if order doesn't matter (which it usually doesn't for constructors) — whatever makes your code better.

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much. Now I can sleep better at night;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think my approach would be to build a hash of parameters, and pass it to the constructor once it was complete

It would look like this. I've wrapped the whole thing in a `do` block to limit the scope of `%attr`; it's not essential. of course `condition` has to be a compilable Perl expression

```
my $obj = do {

    my %attr = (
        attr1 => 'value1',
        attr2 => 'value2',
        attr3 => 'valuen',
    );

    $attr{attr4} = 'value4' if condition;

    MyObject->new(%attr);
};
```

Comment: Thanks! This might work, but I did not test it to confirm, as it requires slightly more changes from my initial code.

Comment: Actually I just tested this as well. If we change the "if" line to $attr{attr4} = 'value4' if condition; It works fine as well. Tried to vote you up, but not yet eligible to do that, I guess;-(